# How to embed an image in a PDF using JPod?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to add an image to a generated pdf using the JPod library.

The JPod DrawInLineImagePlain example (at https://github.com/born2snipe/learning-jpod/blob/master/not-in-repo/examples/de/intarsys/pdf/example/content/DrawInlineImagePlain.java) suggests adding images like so (assume a CSCreator creator is previously defined):

```
// image bytes
private byte[] data = new byte[] { (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
    (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170 };

creator.transform(400, 0, 0, 400, 100, 100);
creator.perform("BI");
creator.perform("/W 16 /H 16 /BPC 1 /CS /G ID");
COSString stringData = COSString.create(data);
creator.perform("EI", stringData);

creator.close();
```

However, I cannot do this because JPod no longer supports perform().

It appears that inlineImage() should be able to embed images. JPod documentation describes inlineImage() like so:

> Stroke an inlined image. PDF graphics operators "BI", "ID", "EI".

This led me to assume that inlineImage() can encode all of the graphics operators in the DrawInLineImagePlain example, and can also encode the width, height, bits-per-component, color space, and the image data using the information in the PDImage parameter.

So I tried to parallel the example like so (again assume a CSCreator creator is previously defined):

```
// image bytes
byte[] data = new byte[] { (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170,
     (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170, (byte) 170 };

PDImage imageData = (PDImage) PDImage.META.createNew();
imageData.setBytes(data);
imageData.setHeight(16);
imageData.setWidth(16);
imageData.setBitsPerComponent(1);
imageData.setColorSpace(PDColorSpace.getNamed(PDColorSpace.CN_CS_DeviceGray));

creator.inlineImage(imageData);

creator.close();
```

This, unfortunately produces a blank PDF. What do I need to change to get the image to appear in the PDF?

I'm guessing there's nothing wrong with the document or page setup, since I can substitute this image embedding for text or line drawing, and the text or lines will appear just fine in the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inlineImage` is not implemented in CSCreator, unfortunately. Use `addOperand` to add stuff to the content stream directly. The code for your image would be:

```
content.addOperation(new CSOperation(CSOperators.CSO_BI));
CSOperation operationID = new CSOperation(CSOperators.CSO_ID);
operationID.addOperand(PDImage.DK_W);
operationID.addOperand(COSInteger.create(16));
operationID.addOperand(PDImage.DK_H);
operationID.addOperand(COSInteger.create(16));
operationID.addOperand(PDImage.DK_BPC);
operationID.addOperand(COSInteger.create(1));
operationID.addOperand(PDImage.DK_CS);
operationID.addOperand(PDColorSpace.CN_CS_G);
content.addOperation(operationID);
CSOperation operationEI = new CSOperation(CSOperators.CSO_EI);
operationEI.addOperand(COSString.create(data));
content.addOperation(operationEI);
```

Alternatively add a regular image to your document with `doImage`